# Docker - Nginx + PHP-FPM = reaching timeout

Tags: php, docker, nginx, php-7.2

Simple question: I'm getting `Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded`, but I don't know why: there are a lot of things written about it, but in script I've no set_timeout or anything like that, just in PHP-FPM config I've `php_value[max_execution_time] = 0` and even with this I'm gettting timeout from PHP-FPM's side (nginx is OK, no 504 Gateway Timeout or what's throwing). The thing is long running http request being killed in aprox. 3 mins. Setup is standard nginx + php-fpm (7.2) running in docker.

Thanks for any points!